# How do Xenomorphs grow up without eating anything in a spaceship?

Tags: alien-franchise, alien-1979

There is nothing for Xenomorphs to eat in spaceships, but they grow up very fast after they burst out of their hosts. Don't they need any food to live?

Comment: Maybe Jonesy had like 18 offspring roaming around there.

Comment: Human kids seem to grow up on air, water, and love... At least mine did. Until they were teenagers. Then food became necessary.